# Storing a graph in SQLite - Relational or Flat?

Tags: c#, sqlite, graph, directed-graph

**The Problem**

I need to store a directed graph in an sqlite database and I'm wondering how to solve this.

My first solution was to create two tables, one for the nodes and one for the edges, however I'm unsatisfied with the insertion performance compared to a non-relational model of the problem.

Given a typical graph of 100k nodes, each having 50 outgoing edges, inserting into a relational model takes ~20s vs 7s using a flat approach.

**Actual question**

- Is there anything I can to do speed up the process of inserting the graph into a database with the relational model?
- Am I using the SQLite API in a suboptimal fashion?
- Should I even consider a relational approach, given that it's not *required*, only "nice"?

**Additional information**

I've written two samples to demonstrate my problem:

*Relational Approach*

```
    public sealed class RelationalGraphDatabase
        : IDatabase
    {
        private readonly SQLiteConnection _connection;

        public RelationalGraphDatabase()
        {
            const string fname = @"E:\relational_graph.db";
            if (File.Exists(fname))
                File.Delete(fname);

            var conn = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
                {
                    DataSource = fname
                };
            _connection = new SQLiteConnection(conn.ToString());
            _connection.Open();
            using (
                var command = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE Node (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT)", _connection))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            using (
                var command =
                    new SQLiteCommand(
                        "CREATE TABLE Edges (Node_From INTEGER NOT NULL, Node_To INTEGER, P1 INTEGER NOT NULL, P2 INTEGER NOT NULL, P3 INTEGER NOT NULL, P4 INTEGER NOT NULL)",
                        _connection))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        public void Commit(IEnumerable<Node> values)
        {
            using (SQLiteTransaction transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                using (var command = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO Node (Id, Name) VALUES (@Id, @Name)", _connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Id", DbType.Int64);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", DbType.String);

                    foreach (Node bts in values)
                    {
                        command.Parameters[0].Value = bts.Id;
                        command.Parameters[1].Value = bts.Name;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                using (
                    var command =
                        new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO Edges (Node_From, Node_To, P1, P2, P3, P4) VALUES (@From, @To, @P1, @P2, @P3, @P4)",
                                          _connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add("@From", DbType.Int64);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@To", DbType.Int64);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@P1", DbType.UInt16);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@P2", DbType.UInt16);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@P3", DbType.UInt16);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@P4", DbType.UInt16);

                    foreach (Node bts in values)
                    {
                        foreach (NodeId neighbour in bts.Edges)
                        {
                            command.Parameters[0].Value = (long) bts.Id;
                            command.Parameters[1].Value = null;
                            command.Parameters[2].Value = neighbour.P1;
                            command.Parameters[3].Value = neighbour.P2;
                            command.Parameters[4].Value = neighbour.P3;
                            command.Parameters[5].Value = neighbour.P4;
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Node> Select()
        {
            var ret = new Dictionary<uint, Node>();
            using (var command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Node", _connection))
            {
                using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var bts = new Node
                            {
                                Id = (uint) reader.GetInt64(0),
                                Name = reader.GetString(1),
                                Edges = new List<NodeId>()
                            };
                        ret.Add(bts.Id, bts);
                    }
                }
            }

            string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Edges WHERE Node_From IN ({0})", string.Join(", ", ret.Keys));
            using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, _connection))
            {
                using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var id = (uint) reader.GetInt64(0);
                        int mcc = reader.GetInt32(2);
                        int mnc = reader.GetInt32(3);
                        int lac = reader.GetInt32(4);
                        int ci = reader.GetInt32(5);
                        ret[id].Edges.Add(new NodeId
                            {
                                P1 = (ushort) mcc,
                                P2 = (ushort) mnc,
                                P3 = (ushort) lac,
                                P4 = (ushort) ci
                            });
                    }
                }
            }

            return ret.Values.ToList();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

*Flat Approach*

```
public sealed class FlatGraphDatabase
    : IDatabase
{
    private readonly SQLiteConnection _connection;

    public FlatGraphDatabase()
    {
        const string fname = @"E:\flat_graph.db";
        if (File.Exists(fname))
            File.Delete(fname);

        var conn = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = fname
            };
        _connection = new SQLiteConnection(conn.ToString());
        _connection.Open();
        using (
            var command = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE Node (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Edges TEXT)", _connection))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    public void Commit(IEnumerable<Node> values)
    {
        using (var transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction())
        using (var command = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO Node (Id, Name, Edges) VALUES (@Id, @Name, @Edges)", _connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@Id", DbType.Int64);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Name", DbType.String);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Edges", DbType.String);

            foreach (var bts in values)
            {
                command.Parameters[0].Value = bts.Id;
                command.Parameters[1].Value = bts.Name;
                command.Parameters[2].Value = string.Join(",", bts.Edges);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Node> Select()
    {
        var ret = new List<Node>();
        using (var command = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Node", _connection))
        {
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var bts = new Node
                        {
                            Id = (uint) reader.GetInt64(0),
                            Name = reader.GetString(1),
                            Edges = reader.GetString(2).Split(',').Select(NodeId.Parse).ToList()
                        };
                    ret.Add(bts);
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time in advance :)

Comment: Your usage of the API looks OK to me (transactions are the big thing, and you're using those). Though I'm a bit skeptical of loading the entire graph at once; usually, you use queries to get parts of the graph as needed. When you do that, having a separate `edges` table is a real help, since you can use indexes, joins, foreign keys, etc. on it (doing that on a comma-separated value is impractical).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right that queries based on edges would ne impractical in a flat model, however I forgot to mention that this is not a requirement so far. Currently all queries are based on properties of a node and it isn't likely to change in the future. Is there anything I can do to decrease the amount of time it takes to import the graph?